Дискорд бот на disnake выдаёт ошибку "Приложение не отвечает" однако команда исправно рботает
import disnake
from typing import Optional
from disnake.ext import commands

class Finish(disnake.ui.View):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(timeout = 999999999)
        self.value: Optional[bool]

    @disnake.ui.button(label="Закончить сессию", style=disnake.ButtonStyle.red, disabled=False)
    async def confirm(self, button: disnake.ui.Button, inter: disnake.CommandInteraction):
        await inter.message.edit(view = None)
        self.value = True
        self.stop()

class CMDUsers(commands.Cog):

    def __init__(self,bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_ready(self):
        print(f"Bot {self.bot.user} is ready to work!")

    @commands.slash_command(description = "Начать модерить!")
    async def start(self,ctx, server: str, online: int):
        start_time = disnake.utils.utcnow()
        channel = self.bot.get_channel(1263841892307701801)
        view = Finish()
        role = disnake.utils.get(ctx.author.guild.roles, id = 1259769417966026785)
        message = await channel.send(f":green_circle: {ctx.author.mention} начал модерить на сервере !\n1. {server}\n2. {online}", view = view)
        await ctx.author.add_roles(role)
        await view.wait()
        time = disnake.utils.utcnow() - start_time
        thread = await ctx.message.create_thread(message = message, name = "Вышел")
        await thread.send(f"Промодерил {str(time)[:-10]}")
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role)

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(CMDUsers(bot))

Дискорд как бы должен получить ответ от бота, но бот отправляет сообщение с помощью channel.send() и ошибка остаётся, если же заменить на ctx.send() то ошибка пропадёт, однако дальше по ходу выполнения команды должна создаться ветка, чего не происходит. Как сделать так что бы всё было красиво?


Это происходит потому что бот отправляет сообщение отдельно, а не как ответ. Чтоб это исправить нужно отправить сообщение, как я уже сказал, в виде ответа. Это делается вроде через функцию reply. Вот ссылка на неё в документации: https://docs.disnake.dev/en/v2.8.2/api.html#disnake.Message.reply .
